# Regex match table row of table have multi row

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code:

```
<table>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>&nbsp; 1</td>
        <td>&nbsp; 1</td>
        <td>&nbsp; 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp; 2</td>
        <td>&nbsp; 2</td>
        <td>&nbsp; 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>&nbsp; 3</td>
        <td>&nbsp; 3</td>
        <td>&nbsp; 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp; 4</td>
        <td>&nbsp; 4</td>
        <td>&nbsp; 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to get the content inside each table row with a regular expression

My Pattern: `<tr(?: class="odd")>[^]+</tr>`

But it only matches last `tr` tag.

Comment: Do you have javascript anywhere?

Comment: What about using a DOM or something?

Comment: Don't know about JS, but in Perl, `[^]` produces this error `[  <-- Unbalanced  '['  ^]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regexes are generally greedy, so it will match as much as possible before progressing to the `</tr>`portion of the regex.  You can match reluctantly by adding a `?`, like:

```
<tr(?: class="odd")>[^]+?</tr>
```

That said, I absolutely agree with others that jQuery (among other tools) is almost certainly the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use [jQuery](http://jquery.org) instead of a regular expression?

```
$('table > tr').each(function() {
  var trInnerHtml = $(this).html();
  alert(trInnerHtml);
});
```

Comment: It is not DOM, it's just a string

Comment: Agreed, you need something other than jQuery if you do not have a document object.